# Get tokens from azure login

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm using Azure AD to login to spring boot application. Although I can log in I need to see user information witch would come with bearer token. How could I get this token when user is redirected back from azure login *(https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{adId}}/oauth2/token)* back to application ?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                .oidcUserService(oidcUserService);
    }


}
```

Comment: I have done this in C# not in JAVA and I believe logic of getting user info from access token is same in all languages. If you have the access token then that should contain the user id value. For retrieving the user info you have to query the Graph API. The full documentation on that is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151678.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As Amogh said, the logic for getting the user info from the access token is the same in different languages. There is a well-documented Azure Sample that does what you are trying to achieve in Java. Please visit and clone [this sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect/) to get the bearer token.

Take a look at the [AAD Controller](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/adal4jsample/AadController.java) section specifically:

```
    URL url = new URL("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
    int httpResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

    String goodRespStr = HttpClientHelper.getResponseStringFromConn(conn, true);
    // logger.info("goodRespStr ->" + goodRespStr);
    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    JSONObject response = HttpClientHelper.processGoodRespStr(responseCode, goodRespStr);
    JSONArray users;

    users = JSONHelper.fetchDirectoryObjectJSONArray(response);

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    User user;
    for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject thisUserJSONObject = users.optJSONObject(i);
        user = new User();
        JSONHelper.convertJSONObjectToDirectoryObject(thisUserJSONObject, user);
        builder.append(user.getUserPrincipalName() + "<br/>");
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Seems so. I'm trying to get this code using not maven but gradle but sadly it's quite complicated.